# How to find all the tags of each page and then concat the tags into one column?

Tags: php, mysql, tagging, group-concat, concatenation

How can I find all the tags of each page and then concat the tags into one column?

For an example,

pages table,

```
page_id 
1
2
3
4
```

tags table,

```
tag_id      tag_name
1           A
2           B
3           C
4           D
```

tagged table,

```
page_id     tag_id
1           1
1           2
1           3
3           2
3           3
```

My working query,

```
SELECT
    p.page_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name ORDER BY t.tag_name ASC SEPARATOR ",") AS tags

FROM root_pages AS p

LEFT JOIN root_mm_pages_tags AS m
ON p.page_id = m.page_id

LEFT JOIN root_tags AS t
ON t.tag_id = m.tag_id

WHERE p.page_id = t.page_id
```

This is the result I am after,

```
page_id         tags
1               A, B, C
2               NULL
3               B, C
4               NULL
```

Comment: +1 For having doing many-to-many the right way.

Comment: thanks  NullUserException! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it without `ON p.page_id = tt.page_id` and `WHERE p.page_id = t.page_id`; also make the last join a regular one for performance.

```
SELECT
    p.page_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name ORDER BY t.tag_name ASC SEPARATOR ",") AS tags

FROM root_pages AS p

LEFT JOIN root_mm_pages_tags AS m
ON p.page_id = m.page_id

JOIN root_tags AS t
ON t.tag_id = m.tag_id

GROUP BY p.page_id
```

Comment: sorry ` ON p.page_id = tt.page_id` was my mistake.

Comment: np. it's almost weekend, after all... oh wait.

Comment: I have tried your answer but it only returns one row with repeated tags in the columns of `tag`...:(

Comment: @lauthiamkok can we see a dump of your tables so we have some data to test with?

Comment: oh I got it worked by adding this line at the end of the query `GROUP BY p.page_id` :-)